# when press ok in dialog box server method execute and if press cancel stay on my page. how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use a dialog box (ok and cancel) in my aspx page.

When I press "ok" my server side code should execute and when I press "cancel" nothing should happen and even though post back also should not done.

The workflow I'm trying to achieve is:

- Press 'save'(aspx button control)
- the *javascript* function which has the *dialogbox* code

  - if press <kbd>ok</kbd> -> server side method execute
  - if press <kbd>cancel</kbd> -> stay on my page only

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome here yadagiri, please edit your post and clarify what do you mean with _"and even though post back also should not done..."_. You can edit your post with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24716536/edit) or pressing the edit link below your question. Provide if you can an example of your previous attempt too.

Comment: "server side method execute" - I believe that's called "code-behind" in the IIS/.Net family.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a "Yes / No" alert box in C# code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831366/display-a-yes-no-alert-box-in-c-sharp-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to have an onclick event like this (written from the top of my head, untested):

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

This should pass a return false to the onclick event if they click cancel (thereby cancelling the click event) and true if they click Ok. If it's an ASP button then the event is OnClientClick rather than OnClick.

To call a function, the event handler would be:

```
onClientClick="return YourJavascriptFunction();"
```

where the function is like this:

```
function YourJavascriptFunction() {
  return confirm("Are you sure?");
}
```

Obviously the function could do a lot more than just that, but it needs to return the result of the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via javascript/jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("someButtonId").onclick = function() {
        var confirmation = window.confirm("Are you sure?"); //confirmation variable will contain true/false.

        if(confirmation) { 
           vvar dataValue = { "name": "myName", "isGoing": "toAPlace", "returnAddress": "anyAddress" };

           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/OnSubmit",
           data: dataValue,
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " +       errorThrown);
             },
          complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
              alert("complete: " + status + "\n\nResponse: " + jqXHR.responseText);
          }
        });

        }
        else { /* do nothing */ }
    }
</script>
```

In this case you add a click event to your button in which this event open up a confirmation. If the user responds "yes", the following `OnSubmit`function from the Default.aspx page, would be called:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    // method called from the javascript
    [WebMethod]
    public static string OnSubmit(string name, bool isGoing, string returnAddress)
    {
        return "it worked";
    }
}
```

Finally, observe in the javascript the even the failure case was handled.