# Create a customized alert box in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a alert box with asp controls, is it possible?

For example, a simple script alert would be like,

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Alert Box');</script>");
```

On the alert box there are default buttons "Ok" and "Cancel" with the text "Alert Box"

Now all i want to do is call a function written in the respective `Demo.aspx.cs` page on the click of Ok button of alert.

Or

Is it possible to place a `asp:Button` control in that alert box to call that function?

Thanks if any of you could help!  :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831366/display-a-yes-no-alert-box-in-c-sharp-code-behind?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `asp:Button` in JavaScript alert, The best way to make an alert or modal dialog box in asp.net is to create your own and make it hidden or in-active in master page and call it when you need it.

You can get a ready made modal or alert in [GetBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

**Update:**
Here some Idea how to use bootstrap modal.

This is how I use GetBootstrap Modal for asp.net webforms, you can use it if you want.

The following code is use to create a customize alert or modal box with proper asp.net button controls that you can use in back-end. *"you can place this in master page to prevent repetitive"*

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAlertBox" runat="server" style="position:absolute;top:0;> //You can make is visible or hidden -- you need to customize the style of panel
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">This is customize alertbox</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    This is the messages...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Cancel" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Ok" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

[image]

But of course you need to include the getboostrap `.js` and `.css` files in master page to show the design.

Place this in header:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Place this after form:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes you can. See my answer.

Comment: @sh1rts OK, The alert box was popup... ups... but something is missing? the asp.net controls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fixed version of Abrar Jahin's answer. Calling e.preventDefault() prevents the default action being taken, which is to submit the form.

The following displays the alert on click, *and then* submits the form: -

```
$("#alert_button").click( function(e)
{
    alert('This is a custom alert box', 'Alert Dialog');
});
```

EDIT:

If you want to call a specific function in your webpage, you have a few options: -

- A PageMethod or HttpHandler
- in your client-side code, call the ASP.NET-generated `__doPostback` function, and pass parameters indicating what to do to your server-side code

Comment: Please read the question "I want to create a alert box with asp controls".

Comment: Thanks I did read it, and my answer has been marked as an answer.

Comment: Congrats, you can predict the future.

Answer (score 0):

without redirect page alert code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Demo');", true);
```

with redirect page

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('Demo');window.location='Demo.aspx';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript inside OnClientClick event handler for the button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete User" 
     OnClientClick="return  confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');" />
```